# terminology: euler form and trigonometric form

Tags: terminology, complex-numbers

Am I right, that the following is the so-called *trigonometric form* of the complex number $c \in \mathbb{C}$?

$|c| \cdot (\cos \alpha + \mathbf{i} \sin \alpha)$

And the following is the Euler form of the very same number, right?

$|c|\cdot \mathbf{e}^{\mathbf{i}\alpha}$

I think there must be a mistake in one of my tutor's notes..

Comment: For the second one I don't know if it's called Euler Form but perhaps the name comes from Euler's Formula $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$.

Comment: yes. The second version is often named 'exponential form'.

Comment: [polar form of complex number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form)

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, and can also be called "polar coordinates" for the complex number.

Comment: @GEdar, if in one exercise is asked to write the solutions of an equation in Euler form, is it the same if I write them in polar / trigonometric form? I mean, Euler form and polar / trigonometric form stand exactly for the same representation of the complex numbers? I know how to convert a complex number from rectagular to trigonometric form but it is the first time that I hear about the Euler form